# What sequences where the difference between their consecutive terms is always a fibonacci numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

What sequence where the difference between its consecutive terms is always a fibonacci numbers ?

I am trying to figure out a pattern in this sequence :

1,2,4,7,12,20,33,54,88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding $1$ to each number and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is $a(n) = a(n-1)+a(n-2)+1,$ $a(0)=-1,a(1)=1.$ Then $a(2)=2, a(3)=4$ and so on.

Comment: No I don't think so. Is there some expression more simpler than that ?

Comment: No, that is true. It can't be more simple expression  than the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We will proceed *mechanically*. Let $a_n$ be the $n$-th term of our sequence. Let $b_n=a_{n}-a_{n-1}$. We are told that the sequence $(b_n)$ obeys the Fibonacci recurrence, so $b_{n+1}=b_n+b_{n-1}$.

Substituting, we obtain
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}-a_{n-2},$$
which simplifies to
$$a_{n+1}=2a_n-a_{n-2}.$$
Now use your favourite method. One way is to note that the characteristic polynomial is $x^3-2x^2+1$.